# Bootstrap carousel shows 3 and advance 1 but it stacks vertically on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, slider

I have a Bootstrap carousel (slider) that shows 3 images and advances 1 each time.

It stacks vertically when it's in mobile view mode (screen width < 768); I want it to collapse into showing only one slide at a time and to keep advancing one slide at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to do that manually , there's no option that allows you to accomplish this functionality